# How to get the response by JUNIT with SOAPUI

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, soapui

I'm running my *SOAPUI* project from *Eclipse*. When project is executed I need to show the response of a specific *testStep* in Eclipse.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: I edit your question to put a bit of context. Also the image it's good and explain perfectly your problem, but please add your code to the question in order that we can play with it to found a solution `:)`. [See this for the next time `:)`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you maybe tried the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/model/iface/Response.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the context using your `TestRunner` instance and then use `expand` method to get your property. In your case:

```
...
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject( "/path/to/Soapui/project.xml" );
TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName( "testSuiteName" );
TestCase testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName( "testCaseName" );
TestRunner runner = test.run(new PropertiesMap(), false );
assertEquals( Status.FINISHED, runner.getStatus() );
// get context and expand the properties
runner.getRunContext().expand("${Test Request#Response}")

....
```

For more info you can check the API: [`TestRunner.getRunContext()`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestRunner.html#getRunContext()) and [`TestRunContext.expand(java.lang.String)`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestRunContext.html#expand(java.lang.String))

Note that to use `expand`, the first part of the `String` passed is the *testStep* **name** and the second part is the **property** you want to get: `${testStepName#Property}`.

In your case to get the *Response* you can use `${Test Request#Response}`.

If as you comment instead of the whole response you want to get a node value you can apply an *XPath* using `expand` with the follow notation:

`${testStepName#Response#XPath}`

So for your case to get the value of `<STATUS_MSG>` you can do it with:

`${Test Request#Response#//*:STATUS_MSG}`

Hope it helps,

Comment: I hope it help me, but what's porperty in my context? I tried write the response name and not worked. @albciff

Comment: @LucasNeves if you want to get the full response simply use `${Test Request#Response}`.

Comment: Thanks,  it's helps very much ^^ tks tks tks

Comment: answer accepted! just one more question.. if I want to show just the "Status_msg" tag of my XML? The code ${Test Request#STATUS_MSG} don't work

Comment: @LucasNeves now I can explain the notation because I'm on mobile... but you can try with: `${Test Request#Response#//*:STATUS_MSG}`